# React reactquery and formik initialvalues async problem

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, formik, react-query

```
const {productid} = useParams()

const  {isLoading,isErr,data,err} =useQuery([`Admin`,productid],() =>  fetchProduct(productid))
   
const formik = useFormik({
    initialValues: {title:data?.title,
      description:`${data?.description}`,
      price:`${data?.price}`,
      photos:data?.photos},
      onSubmit:()=>{}
    }
   )
```

In this code, I have delay for this reason, formik every time send me null so you see the formik initial values its need to be a loaded data come.

If I can useQuery.then(formik) my problem is solve. But you know the react rules so how can I solve this problem ?

Comment: You can use the `isLoading` prop of your `useQuery` to delay rendering of the form until the query completes. i.e. `const { data, isLoading } = useQuery(['Admin', productId], () => fetchProduct()); if (isLoading) { return <Loading />; } const formik = useFormik...`

Comment: @nbokmans when i doing that : src\pages\Admin\AdminProductDetail\index.js
  Line 12:18:  React Hook "useFormik" is called conditionally. React Hooks must be called in the exact same order in every component render  react-hooks/rules-of-hooks

Search for the keywords to learn more about each error.

Comment: Yeah, that's because you are using `useFormik` hook (not recommended, see docs: https://formik.org/docs/api/useFormik) to create your form rather than using Formik component `<Formik initialValues={{ title: data?.title }} onSubmit={() => { }}> </Formik>`

Comment: @nbokmans i try to component formik but  its not working well so i want to use like this hook style is any can be fix ?

Comment: @Foxsnow you should try that: https://formik.org/docs/api/formik#enablereinitialize-boolean The only issue is im affraid it will work only with Formik component usage, not a hook, as i see per github issues, but you can try anyway, maybe they fixed that already. https://github.com/jaredpalmer/formik/issues/2397

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that a `useEffect` that sets values whenever `data` changes is the right thing to do in many cases, because with react-query, background updates can happen that might change the `data` and then your user input will be overwritten.

I've gone into details about a couple of approaches in my blog: https://tkdodo.eu/blog/react-query-and-forms

The simplest thing is really to split it up into two components:

```
const { data } = useQuery(...)

if (!data) return 'loading...'

return <Form initialData={data} />
```

then inside `Form`, you can call `useFormik` and set the initial values, because it will only be mounted as soon as data is available.

Answer (score -1):

i find to solution thanks to @Sergey-Sosunov

```
 const  {isLoading,isErr,data,err} =useQuery([`Admin`,productid],() =>  fetchProduct(productid))

  const initialData ={title:data?.title,
    description:data?.description,
    price:data?.price,
    photos:data?.photos}

    useEffect(()=>{
formik.setValues({...initialData})
},[data])  

  const formik = useFormik({
    enableReinitialize: true,
    initialValues: initialData,
      onSubmit:()=>{}
    }
   )
```

Comment: please see my answer - useEffect can get you in trouble: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73136523/8405310